# Error reading pandas DataFrame from file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a file using DataFrame.from_csv() in python pandas. The file contains this value.

```
TICKER,date,ASKHI,PRC,BIDLO,PortfolioDate,PortfolioName
MSFT,2012-06-29 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-07-31 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-08-31 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-09-28 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-10-31 00:00:00,28.88,28.54,28.5,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
```

But, when I am accessing I read it from dataframe the frame generates like this.

```
     date  ASKHI    PRC  BIDLO        PortfolioDate  \
TICKER                                                                  
MSFT    2012-06-29 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
MSFT    2012-07-31 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
MSFT    2012-08-31 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
MSFT    2012-09-28 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
MSFT    2012-10-31 00:00:00  28.88  28.54   28.5  2010-12-31 00:00:00   

       PortfolioName  
TICKER                
MSFT          SAP500  
MSFT          SAP500  
MSFT          SAP500  
MSFT          SAP500  
MSFT          SAP500
```

when I choose the column 'date' by  using frame['date'], the result is:

```
TICKER
MSFT      2012-06-29 00:00:00
MSFT      2012-07-31 00:00:00
MSFT      2012-08-31 00:00:00
MSFT      2012-09-28 00:00:00
MSFT      2012-10-31 00:00:00
```

My code is :

```
frame = DataFrame.from_csv('/home/raghu/log.txt',sep=',');
```

I am new to this. Is there something I am missing? Why is the first column like this?

EDIT: Pandas version :'0.14.1'

Comment: Don't use `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv` it's outdated, use `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: Also note that if you don't like this behaviour and for some reason you can't get around it you can always reset the index: `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: pandas.read_csv didn't work as I failed to remove the default index. Anyway, I used dataframe.to_csv(index=False) to regenerate the csv afterwards, which worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [`from_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_csv) it is no longer maintained, instead use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
In [112]:
import io
temp="""TICKER,date,ASKHI,PRC,BIDLO,PortfolioDate,PortfolioName
MSFT,2012-06-29 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-07-31 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-08-31 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-09-28 00:00:00,NA,NA,NA,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500
MSFT,2012-10-31 00:00:00,28.88,28.54,28.5,2010-12-31 00:00:00,SAP500"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))

df
Out[112]:
  TICKER                 date  ASKHI    PRC  BIDLO        PortfolioDate  \
0   MSFT  2012-06-29 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
1   MSFT  2012-07-31 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
2   MSFT  2012-08-31 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
3   MSFT  2012-09-28 00:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN  2010-12-31 00:00:00   
4   MSFT  2012-10-31 00:00:00  28.88  28.54   28.5  2010-12-31 00:00:00   

  PortfolioName  
0        SAP500  
1        SAP500  
2        SAP500  
3        SAP500  
4        SAP500  
In [113]:

df['date']
Out[113]:
0    2012-06-29 00:00:00
1    2012-07-31 00:00:00
2    2012-08-31 00:00:00
3    2012-09-28 00:00:00
4    2012-10-31 00:00:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```

The reason you get the strangeness with the first column is because it's treating the first column as the index when you use [`from_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_csv) (the default value for `index_col` is `0`) which [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) does not do (the default value for `index_col` is `None`).

**EDIT**

To fix your error without upgrading just set `index_col=None` in the params to `from_csv`:

```
In [115]:

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=None)
df['date']
Out[115]:
0    2012-06-29 00:00:00
1    2012-07-31 00:00:00
2    2012-08-31 00:00:00
3    2012-09-28 00:00:00
4    2012-10-31 00:00:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried it. But, there is an error "AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'read_csv'". I'm using anaconda, I think their package is outdated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Interestingly, 

frame = pandas.DataFrame.read_csv('testFile.csv',sep=',', index_col = False)

shows the expected result. But, I don't want index to be shown in dataframe

Comment: No it should be `None` not `False`

Comment: I hope it is the problem with pandas in anaconda.  I tried it with None, but it is still showing the index!!

Comment: Please edit this to your question rather than as a comment as the formatting will be lost, also add your pandas version